# Using string as object field to reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is an example of what I am trying to accomplish and as expected it is not working.

Is there something similar that would work?

```
var fieldsToCheck = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

for (var i = 0; i < fieldsToCheck.length; i++){
    var field = fieldsToCheck[counter];
    if (!obj.field) {
         console.log('There is no field of: ' + field);
    }
 }
```

I originally did this using only if statements for every field, I am wondering whether or not there is a faster way to do this.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `obj.a` equates to `obj["a"]` equates to `prop = "a"; obj[prop]`

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the properties in that way. Since it's a variable, you have to use brackets instead of the dot notation:

```
var fieldsToCheck = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

for (var i = 0; i < fieldsToCheck.length; i++){
    var field = fieldsToCheck[counter];
    if (!obj[field]) {
         console.log('There is no field of: ' + field);
    }
 }
```

When you use the dot notation e.g. `obj.field`, you're essentially asking if `obj` has a key `field`, rather than if `obj` has a key that is the value of variable `field`. For anything where you're accessing either unknown or string keys that contain non-variable valid characters like `-`, you'll have to use the bracket notation like `obj[field]` or `obj["a"]`.

Comment: make sure you accept the answer when you're able to :-)